# "Combined by" or "combined with"?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is grammatically correct and why
 'the magnanimous sales of Diwali combined by our thorough research'
or
'the magnanimous sales of Diwali combined with our thorough research'

if explained, would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"by" indicates means. That is, "X combined by Y" means "X was combined, and Y was used to do so". For instance, one can say "I combined the ingredients by hand". "with" means that it was part of the combination. That is, "X combined with Y" means that X and Y were combined.

Comment: Thanks loads! Much needed explanation.

Comment: So that means, in the sentence I asked above, by would be correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to ELL!

Did you try using a dictionary first?

I typed

> '"combine" meaning'

into [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=Gi-0XZ7pMpqR8gL7rJqIDw&q=%22combine%22%20neaning&oq=%22combine%22%20neaning&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i13l10.9628.13489..14019...0.2..0.79.661.10......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i7i30j0j0i22i30j0i22i10i30j0i13i10.-SXXxRvMuls&ved=0ahUKEwie3oye6rnlAhWaiFwKHXuWBvEQ4dUDCAo&uact=5). The first two lines of the first result were:

> 1. join or merge to form a single unit or substance.
>      "combine the flour with the margarine and salt"

So you need **combined with**.

Unfortunately

> 'the magnanimous sales of Diwali'

is *nonsense*. Magnanimous means generous and it is most often used to describe the winner's attitude towards the loser.

Comment: Sales of Diwali are generous too, and can be used without a doubt. Thanks for the dictionary idea. I did check the dictionary but I wasn't able to infer anything. Thanks though

Comment: Magnanimous also means grand. I've got it checked from other people too. Don't know why you find it senseless

Comment: "Magnanimous sales" is poor English. There is *not one single example* of the phrase in NGram.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=magnanimous+sales&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=

Comment: Magnanimous meaning grand? No sign of it here. https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/magnanimous?s=t

Comment: @RS2000 We might say 'sales of Diwali', but 'Diwali sales' or 'sales over Diwali' would be more likely. I've never heard the expression 'sales of Christmas'; though 'Christmas sales' and 'sales over Christmas' are common. For a newcomer your tone is remarkably discourteous.

Comment: Apologies if you found me rude. Didn't intend to revert back in that manner but saying nonsense isn't courteous either.

Comment: The sources you have provided aren't used my country at all. I've read sales of Diwali multiple times on posters in my country.

Comment: And magnanimous is grand was taught in my school. Sir, English is a tricky language. Can't really help about it!

Comment: I apologise again. I'm extremely sorry.

Comment: @RS2000 Not at all! Yes - English is really tricky! Never mind! Happy Diwali!

Comment: Happy Diwali! Thanking you sir for all your inputs.